# Trouble getting WebView and anonymous BroadcastReceiver communicating in an Activity

Tags: android

I want an anonymous BroadcastReceiver to respond to links inside of a WebView. I thought I could do this with intent-filters, but things are not working. Here is the code for my Activity:

```
public class WebViewReceiverActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.loadData("<a href=\"webview-receiver:///\">This should Toast</a>", "text/html", "utf8");

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                if (data != null && data.getScheme().equals("webview-receiver")) {
                    Toast.makeText(WebViewReceiverActivity.this, "Toasty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intentFilter.addDataScheme("webview-receiver");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


}
```

Here is the main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When clicking the link in the WebView I get a page not found error and no Toast. Is this approach possible? I am thinking about just using WebViewClient and shouldOverrideUrlLoading() instead, but if I can get the BroadcastReceiver approach working than I would prefer that.

Comment: use a javascript to java interface to response to clicks in a web view http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a hybrid approach between the BroadcastReceiver and the WebViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("webview-receiver")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);

            sendBroadcast(intent);

            return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I am doing this because of constraints of the current code base I am working on. It would probably be much simpler to just do all the logic of the BroadcastReceiver onReceive() method in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method.